# Почему в не определяется Descriptor, определяющий свойства метода класса в декораторе TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, декоратор

Пытаюсь изучить Декораторы методов в TypeScript.  В примере попоробую декорировать метод внутри класса `getUserInDataBase()` декоратором `@Log` и descriptor определяется как undefined, то есть не видит реализацию метода `getUserInDataBase()` я уже что только не пробовал.

```
interface IUserService {
  users: number;
  getUserInDataBase(): number;
}

class UserService implements IUserService {
  users: number = 1000;

  @Log
  getUserInDataBase(): number {
    return this.users;
  }
}

function Log(
  target: Object,
  propertyKey: string | symbol,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any>
): TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any> | void {
  console.log(descriptor);
  const oldMethod = descriptor.value
  descriptor.value = () => {
    console.log("Some text");
    return oldMethod()

  };
}

console.log(new UserService().getUserInDataBase());
```

При компиляции получаю ошибки:

```
decoratorMethod.ts:9:3 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 3.

9   @Log
    ~~~~

  decoratorMethod.ts:18:3
    18   descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any>
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    An argument for 'descriptor' was not provided.

decoratorMethod.ts:9:4 - error TS1270: Decorator function return type 'void | TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any>' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => number)'.
  Type 'TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: any[]) => any>' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => number)'.

9   @Log
     ~~~


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: decoratorMethod.ts:9
```

А при запуске скомпилированого _.js получаю:

```
undefined
D:\JS\TS\decorators\decoratorMethod.js:57
    descriptor.value = function () {
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')
    at Log (D:\JS\TS\decorators\decoratorMethod.js:57:22)
    at __esDecorate (D:\JS\TS\decorators\decoratorMethod.js:19:40)
    at D:\JS\TS\decorators\decoratorMethod.js:51:13
    at D:\JS\TS\decorators\decoratorMethod.js:52:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\JS\TS\decorators\decoratorMethod.js:54:2)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)

Node.js v18.12.0
```

При этом в настройках `tsconfig`

```
"compilerOptions": {

"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

для TS > 5.0 :

```json
{
  "experimentalDecorators": false,
}
```

и тогда немножко иные параметры декоратора

А при включенных экспериментальных декораторах:

```json
{
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
}
```

```js
interface IUserService {
  users: number;
  get UserInDataBase(): number;
}

class UserService implements IUserService {
  users: number = 1000;

  @Log
  get UserInDataBase(): number {
    return this.users;
  }
}

function Log<R extends {}, P>(
  target: R,
  propertyKey: keyof R,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<P>
): TypedPropertyDescriptor<P> | void {
  console.log(descriptor);
  const oldAccessor = descriptor.get;
  if (oldAccessor === undefined) throw "Decorator is only allowed on getters";

  descriptor.get = function (this: R) {
    // @ts-ignore
    console.log(`decorating ${propertyKey}`);
    return oldAccessor.call(this);
  };
}

console.log(new UserService().UserInDataBase);
```